# Sort a list using partial match with vector (r)

Tags: r, list, sorting, vector

I'm trying to reorder the elements in a list based on a partial match with a string vector. So that if I had the following list:

```
    myList = list(BvsAadditionalinfo, AvsAothertext,
 BvsBothertext, AvsBothertext, AvsBadditionalinfo,
 BvsAothertext, BvsBadditionalinfo, AvsAadditionalinfo)
```

And a vector such as this:

```
vsList = c("AvsA", "AvsB", "BvsA", "BvsB")
```

I could sort my list so that I ended up with:

```
    myList = list(AvsAothertext, AvsAadditionalinfo,
 AvsBothertext, AvsBadditionalinfo, BvsAothertext,
 BvsAadditionalinfo, BvsBothertext, BvsBadditionalinfo)
```

I've tried using things along the lines of `order`:

```
TempFileList <- [order(match(myList, vsList))]
```

But it doesn't appear to work, presumably because the match isn't 100%. How can I tell it to accept a partial match?

I also don't have any attachment to my vsList, so I could just as easily use something like this:

```
abbreviations = c("A", "B")
```

If it would work.

Comment: Is each item of the `vsList` always 4 characters? If so, you could do something like `order(match(lapply(myList,substr,1,4), vsList))` but obviously that won't work if it might change length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList = list(BvsAadditionalinfo = 0, AvsAothertext = 0,
              BvsBothertext = 0, AvsBothertext = 0,
              AvsBadditionalinfo = 0, BvsAothertext = 0,
              BvsBadditionalinfo = 0, AvsAadditionalinfo = 0)

myList[order(-rowSums(sapply(seq_along(vsList), function(i)
    i * grepl(vsList[i], names(myList)))), names(myList), decreasing = TRUE)]
#$`AvsAothertext`
#[1] 0

#$AvsAadditionalinfo
#[1] 0

#$AvsBothertext
#[1] 0

#$AvsBadditionalinfo
#[1] 0

#$BvsAothertext
#[1] 0

#$BvsAadditionalinfo
#[1] 0

#$BvsBothertext
#[1] 0

#$BvsBadditionalinfo
#[1] 0
```